# create a square of colors with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a class or a possible solution to create a `div` or picture using jQuery and fill it with smaller squares like this:

[image]

Is jQuery capable of doing this?

Comment: @alex yes that would be fine i wouldn't mind

Comment: This is not a core function of jQuery. I think you'll find a jQuery plugin doing this, but this can also be made in pure Javascript

Comment: @rabudde would you know how to accomplish that in javascript?

Comment: you will have to provide the colors your self, or using some values using rgb values

Comment: get http://plugins.jquery.com/project/icolor and edit it for what you want

Comment: This can be coded in pure static HTML with no Javascript required.  It's just a grid of divs with background-colors set to match the desired color swatches.  If you insist on creating it with javascript, we'd need to know how the color values are assigned.  jQuery is not needed for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another example along the same lines:

```
var unitSize = 16; // width (and height) of one square
var unitsWide = 6; // number of squares along x-axis
var unitsTall = 6; // number of squares along y-axis
var drawing = $('<div class="drawing"></div>').css({
    overflow: 'hidden',
    border: '16px solid #000000',
    width: unitSize * unitsWide
});
for (var i = 0; i < unitsWide * unitsTall; i++) {
    var randomColor;
    randomColor = Math.random() * 0x1000000; // 0 < randomColor < 0x1000000
    randomColor = Math.floor(randomColor); // 0 < randomColor <= 0xFFFFFF
    randomColor = randomColor.toString(16); // hex representation randomColor
    randomColor = ("000000" + randomColor).slice(-6); // leading zeros added
    randomColor = "#" + randomColor; // # added
    $('<span class="square"></span>').css({
        display: 'block',
        float: 'left',
        width: unitSize,
        height: unitSize,
        'background-color': randomColor
    }).appendTo(drawing);
}
drawing.appendTo($("body"));
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/xfSQJ/)

Comment: Note that you may want to use [HSL/HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) colors instead of RGB. Manipulating these colors makes more sense and can easily be converted from/to RGB for use in CSS.

Comment: I didnt think about that. I tried your demo and its working really well and its fast. i tried to add td for the append part and i also tried to add it to a div with a class of txt but it didnt work only works with body. is there a way to change that

Comment: @sarsar: Are you trying to (i) append it to a `td` or (ii) convert the `div/spans` into `table/tr/td`? The first case means you might be making (a little) mistake. The latter case requires little rewriting.

Comment: I think I am making a mistake I would like to append it to this  `<td class="stxt">` so yes the 1st case is what I am interested in accomplishing.

Comment: i made a mistake it was suppose to be after the bold tag but i followed your example with `b.nme pn_reg` but nothing happened maybe you can look at my page and see what i am doing wrong  http://goo.gl/eJWEC (i am using this for a chat service and for anyone who does not have an avatar it will display this square)

Comment: @SalmanA let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1761/discussion-between-sarsar-and-salman-a)

Answer (score 5):

Something like this, maybe:

```
var container = $('<div id="container">');
$('body').append(container);

for (i=0; i<25; i++) {
    // Random colour from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535128/apply-random-color-to-class-elements-individually
    var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ')';
    $('<div class="child">').css('background-color', hue).appendTo(container);
}
```

(Assuming this CSS:)

```
#container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.child {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
}
```

[jsFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/fJ23e/).

Comment: WOW! thank you so much this is perfect. I was trying to make a html table but and fill each box with colors like jfriend00 mentioned but this is just what i had in mind.

Comment: i plan on using this for a php chat. this chat allows users to provide their own avatar. When a user picks an an avatar the code looks like this `<img src="http://website.com/cat.png" class="pic">` is there a way to check for this and if its not there add `<div id="container">`  to this `<tr class="dtxt">`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a plain javascript way to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Ugjfj/

```
function run() {

    var o = document.getElementById("randomBlock");
    if (o) {
        o.parentNode.removeChild(o);
    }

    var rows = 5;
    var cols = 5;
    var size = 30;

    var container = document.createElement("div");
    container.id = "randomBlock";
    container.className = "container";
    container.style.width = (cols * size) + "px";
    container.style.height = (rows * size) + "px";

    for (var i = 0, len = rows * cols; i < len; i++) {
        o = document.createElement("div");
        o.className = "cell";
        o.style.height = size + "px";
        o.style.width = size + "px";
        o.style.backgroundColor = getRandomBlue();
        container.appendChild(o);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(container);
}

function getRandomBlue() {
    var luminosity = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    return("rgb(" + luminosity + "," + luminosity + "," + blue + ")");
}

window.onload = run;
```