# how to specify a background color for every tr element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having multiple tr with bgcolors like

```
<tr bgcolor="#OC6110">
<tr bgcolor="#000000">
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
```

I want to give different bg color for every `tr` element without specifying its id value. I need to make changes in javascript or CSS. I don't want to touch in HTML.

Is it possible?

Already some bgcolors are given in html..I need to overwrite it without touching html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function to get a random color

```
function get_color() {
    var lt= '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += lt[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

And apply the color using

```
$("tr").each(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", get_color());
});
```

[source and more solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540301/applying-a-random-background-colour-to-multiple-divs)

---

**Update:**

As per comment, you can store the color values in an array and use them like this:

```
var myColors = ['#f00','#ff0','#fff'];//store the color values here

$("tr").each(function() {
   for(var i=0; i<myColors.length;i++){    
     $(this).css("background-color", myColors[i]);
   }
});
```

Comment: I want to mention the particular bgcolor for every tr..How to identify the particular tr from html page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery

```
$('tr:odd').css("background-color", "#OC6110");

$('tr:even').css("background-color", "#000000");
```

Comment: I need it in javascript or CSS..No jquery

Comment: Explain your answer please.

Comment: <table border="1">
<tr><td>Row with Index #0</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row with Index #1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row with Index #2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row with Index #3</td></tr>
</table>
<script>
$( "tr:odd" ).css( "background-color", "#bbbbff" );$('tr:even').css("background-color", "#000000");
</script>

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this

```
$(function() {
    $("table tr").each(function() {
        var color = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ')';
         $(this).css("background-color", color);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can get a list of all `tr` elements with `document.getElementsByTagName('tr')` You can then step over the elements in that NodeList (like an array, with subtle differences), using `setAttribute('bgColor', yourNewTextStringRepresentingAColorHere);`

Something like this:

```
function colourAllTrs()
{
  var trList = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  var i, n = trList.length;
  for (i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    newColor = '#123456';
    trList[i].setAttribute('bgcolor', newColor);
  }
}
```

You can use `C-link`'s getColor function, instead of simply using #123456.

Answer (score 0):

Try this JavaScript Solution.

```
var colors = ['#999999','#000000','#cccccc'],
    myTrs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for(i=0, len = myTrs.length; i < len; i++){
    myTrs[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i % colors.length]
};
```

<kbd>[**Updated Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rRK94/2/)</kbd>

Comment: I have mentioned without specifying its id value

Comment: what is myTable? it is table name which we mentioned in html right? I have asked without changing in html..I need to code in css or javascript..

Comment: Yes, It's <table> tag name in html and we are not doing any change in html

Comment: Do you have any idea about how to change tr bgcolor by calculating its number of counts in html page