# Easiest way to put different background colours to each diffrent element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently making something like this:

```
<div id="container">
 <div class="gridTab">
  Home
 </div>
 <div class="gridTab">
  Work
 </div>
 <div class="gridTab">
  Gallery
 </div>
 <div class="gridTab">
  Contact
 </div>
</div>
```

That each "gridTab" should have different colour. From the top to bottom.

Comment: Add a different sub class to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nth-child` pseudo class

```
.gridTab:nth-child(1){background:red}
.gridTab:nth-child(2){background:lime}
.gridTab:nth-child(3){background:green}
.gridTab:nth-child(4){background:violet}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CXKvv/1/)**

---

If you are looking for IE9 below solution then use the following method

**For IE7+ Support**

```
.gridTab:first-child {background:red}
.gridTab:first-child + div.gridTab{background:lime}
.gridTab:first-child + div + div.gridTab{background:green}
.gridTab:first-child + div + div + div.gridTab{background:violet}
```

**[DEMO for IE7+](http://jsfiddle.net/CXKvv/2/)**

Comment: @Yoggi Yes absolutely correct. `css 3.0` not supported by ie8.

Comment: @Yoggi updated the answer with another method for IE8 and below

Comment: @Sowmya: I have one query, lets say we have 1000 or lets say 100 div's  with `gridTab` class, do we have to write `.gridTab:first-child {background: some_color}` line of code 100 times??

Answer (score 1):

You should add another class which makes the difference between the elements.And then style them by that class.

```
<div id="container">
 <div class="gridTab one">
  Home
 </div>
 <div class="gridTab two">
  Work
 </div>
 <div class="gridTab three">
  Gallery
 </div>
 <div class="gridTab four">
  Contact
 </div>
</div>
```

and then CSS:

```
.one {
  background: white;
}
.two{
  background: blue;
}
.three{
  background: red;
}
.four{
  background: black;
}
```

Comment: I am not trying to use CSS here.

Comment: @RedFiction12, if you are not trying to use CSS, what are you trying to use then?

Answer (score 1):

And if you want your colors to be random and differnt, you can use this.It removes the limitations of the number of divs you will need to write styles for.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.gridTab').each(function () {
        var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ')';
        $(this).css("background-color", hue);
    });
});
```

Referenced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535128/apply-random-color-to-class-elements-individually)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple code:

```
$(".gridTab").each(function (i) {
  var colors = ["#CCCCCC", "#333333", "#990099", "#EEEEEE"];
  $(this).css("background-color", colors[i]);
});
```

Comment: but why cant we do this with pure CSS when there are options available in CSS itself

Comment: since the question have a tag [tag:jquery]

Comment: +1 nice thought.. I think it requires incrementing `i`.. right?

Comment: Just do a `console.log(i)` and you will get the answer :)

Comment: no need of that.. as you are not editing your post.. it is clear that there is no need of incrementing :D

Comment: The question is tagged Jquery, he never asked for random colors, so look to my answer that has a similar solution (Still for some unknown reason it has been downvoted).

Comment: Yeah @Mr_Green, anyways the Index `i` is auto-incremented in `jQuery each` function :)

Comment: @Yoggi: Has the OP asked for random or different colors??

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Style sheet using the `nth-child` pseudo like below or you can use the style attribute in the div tag like in the last div.

```
<style>
.gridTab:nth-child(1){background-color: red;}
.gridTab:nth-child(2){background-color: green;}
.gridTab:nth-child(3){background-color: blue;}
.gridTab:nth-child(4){background-color: yellow;}
</style>

<div id="container">
 <div class="gridTab">
  Home
 </div>
 <div class="gridTab">
  Work
 </div>
 <div class="gridTab">
  Gallery
 </div>
 <div class="gridTab" style="background-color: yellow;">
  Contact
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using ID's if you want a specific property for a specific object.

Your CSS:

```
#yellowTab {background-color:yellow;}
#redTab {background-color:red;}
#greenTab {background-color:green;}
#blueTab {background-color:blue;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
 <div class="gridTab" id="yellowTab">
  Home
 </div>
 <div class="gridTab" id="redTab">
  Work
 </div>
 <div class="gridTab" id="greenTab">
  Gallery
 </div>
 <div class="gridTab" id="blueTab">
  Contact
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without css you could do like this with JQuery:

```
$('.gridTab:first').css('background', 'red');
$('.gridTab:second').css('background', 'blue');
```

and so on...

Comment: Why the downvote? @RedFiction12 said: 'I am not trying to use CSS here.', in a comment to another answer. So, I thought he could benefit from a non-CSS solution. It is still valid, so I can't see why this should be downvoted. Even if CSS without JQuery should be the prefered way to go, this solution can be used in more dynamically created situations.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved like this too: http://jsfiddle.net/Ezn26/

```
for (var i = 0; i <= $('.gridTab').length; i++) {     
    $('.gridTab').eq(i).addClass('red').end()
       .next('.gridTab').eq(i).addClass('green').end()
       .next('.gridTab').eq(i).addClass('blue').end()
       .next('.gridTab').eq(i).addClass('yellow');
}
```

Comment: isnt this a lengthy approach? Why are you assigning colors to all the four divs in a single iteration of for loop ?